# Anyone fimilar with building monopoly in visual basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a lot of the program completed, way to big to submit. I cant get this section working though. here is what it is supposed to do. 
Player should be able to move around board, land on a property, and the correct property image load up in a PictureBox (on a seperate form).

This will be done through the use of subproceduress called `WhereAmI()` and `DoneMoving()`. Before we create these, we need to create a variable up at the beginning of the class (where all the property constructors are). Declare the following:

```
Public TempProp as PropertyItem
```

Notice the word New was left out. This will keep it from calling the constructor. TempProp is going to be a holding variable that will reference whatever property we assign it. What this means is that once we load TempProp with the appropriate property reference, we can interact with TempProp and IT WILL INTERACT WITH THE PROPERTY WE ARE REFERENCING! This is going to be highly useful for us. Besides the WhereAmI procedure, all our code can just reference TempProp (as long as we have loaded the appropriate property reference first via the WhereAmI function. Later we will create a another procedure called WhatIsIt that will load TempProp based on name and not location.)

```
WhereAmI(pl as integer)  
    Select Case pl 
        Case 1:
            TempProp = MediterraneanAve
        Case 2:
            TempProp = Nothing
        Case 3: 
            TempProp = BalticAve
        etc.
```

`DoneMoving():` 'This should be called at the end of your movement loop.

```
WhereAmI(playerLocation)
    PropertyForm.ShowDialog()
```

In your PropertyForm, create a PictureBox. In the load event of the form, set

```
PictureBox.image = Form1.TempProp.GetImage()
```

This should load the appropriate property image into the PictureBox. See resources section for an example.

and here is my code.

```
Case 0
TempProp = Go
Case1 :
TempProp = Mediteranean av
Case2: 
tempProp = Nothing
Case 3 
TempProp = Baltic
Case 4
TempProp = Nothing
Case 5 
TempProp = ReadingRailroad
Case 6
TempProp = OrientalAve
Case 7
TempProp = Nothing
Case 8 
TempProp = VermontAve
Case 9 
TempProp = ConnecticutAve
Case 10
TempProp = Jail
Case 11
TempProp = StCharlesPlace
Case 12
TempProp = Nothing
Case 13
TempProp = StatesAve
Case 14
TempProp = VirginiaAve
Case 15
TempProp = PennsylvaniaRR
Case 16
 TempProp = StJamesPlace
Case 17
TempProp = Nothing
Case 18
TempProp = TennesseAve
Case 19
TempProp = NewYorkAve
Case 20
TempProp = FreePark
Case 21
TempProp = KentuckyAve
Case 22
TempProp = Nothing
Case 23
TempProp = IndianaAve
Case 24
TempProp = IllinoisAve
Case 25
TempProp = BORR
Case 26
TempProp = AtlanticAve
Case 27
TempProp = VentnorAve
Case 28
TempProp = Nothing
Case 29
TempProp = MarvinGardens
Case 30 
TempProp = gotojail
Case 31 
TempProp = PacificAve
Case 32
TempProp = NorthCarolinaAve
Case 33
TempProp = Nothing
Case 34 
TempProp = PennsylvaniaAve
Case 35
TempProp = ShortLineRR
Case 36
TempProp = Nothing
Case 37
TempProp = ParkPlace
Case 38
TempProp = Nothing
Case 39 
TempProp = Boardwalk


DoneMoving()
WhereamI (playerlocation)
propertyForm.showDialog()
picture box
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dim my player I figured it out.